# IE 10 Issue when Logged in to another site in another tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-10

This is a weird one: I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app (.NET 4.5). Use ASP.NET forms authentication on the site. Bootstrap is used on the site.

When the user is only logged into that site through Internet Explorer 10 (no matter how many other tabs they have open), the site works fine.

When they log into my site and then log into another site in another tab, my site works fine.

When they log into another site first and then log into my site, IE10 always loses the session. The landing page loads fine but their authorization is lost when they try to browse to another page.

I've set the cookie to a distinct name to separate it from all other .ASPXAUTH cookies, forced it to use cookies for authentication, updated the browser definition files. (Not that I think it's any of those items since the site works fine in the first two situations.) Also, compatibility mode doesn't seem to make a difference. Every other browser I've tested has been fine and even IE10 has been fine other than in the above situation.

I'm at a loss for what to try next. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE (FURTHER INFORMATION): I set the site up on a different server and it ran as would be expected. (Using a custom host header in my HOSTS file.) I then created an additional HOSTS file entry pointing to the original server and the site had the issue as noted above. Any thoughts as to what the issue might be?

Both servers are: Win 2008 R2 64-bit Service Pack 1, IIS 6.1

Comment: Just to be clear, by _“log into another site”_ you mean another site/project/whatever hosted under the same domain?

Comment: No, it can be any other site. We tested with GMail and Microsoft Online and the results as described above: our session wouldn't stay active on our site while the other site (GMail, etc.) was fine.

Comment: Are there any add-ons in this IE you are experiencing this with? If so, does the behavior stay the same if you disable them?

Comment: It's happening across multiple IE instances with no addons. I've since learned it also occurs in IE11. When testing it, it doesn't happen in my test environment so it would seem to be something with the server/network rather than a code/browser issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: I had the Forms Authentication cookie set to be persistent. When I reset it to non-persistent, the login stuck. Not sure why it was an issue, but I'm leaving this here in case has the same problem.